# CORS working with jQuery but not with Prototype

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, cors, prototype

I'm working on the Magento platform but this is really a JS issue I'm having here.

Here's the thing:

I'm **working on an AJAX login feature** and I would like the **login actions to go through HTTPS wherever you're browsing the Magento website in HTTP or HTTPS.**

So I faced this **CORS problem because protocols need to match.**

So I have my Magento controller action code that includes the following:

```
$this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', rtrim(Mage::getUrl(''),'/'))
        ->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials')
        ->setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-json')
        ->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

And I **managed to get it working using the following jQuery code**:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jQuery('#ajaxlogin-login-form').attr('action'),
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        data: jQuery('#ajaxlogin-login-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
     }
 });
```

With this code, when I'm browsing in HTTP and I try to login, **it logs in fine and when I go back to HTTP I can see that I'm logged in.** So far so good.

But I want to avoid using jQuery and **want to do it via prototype** so I tried several things including the following:

```
new Ajax.Request($('ajaxlogin-login-form').action, {
            requestHeaders: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "https://my.dev.website",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
            },
            method: "post",
            parameters: $('ajaxlogin-login-form').serialize(),
            onCreate: function(response) {
                var t = response.transport;
                t.setRequestHeader = t.setRequestHeader.wrap(function(original, k, v) {
                    if (/^(accept|accept-language|content-language|access-control-allow-origin|access-control-allow-headers|access-control-allow-credentials)$/i.test(k))
                        return original(k, v);
                    if (/^content-type$/i.test(k) &&
                        /^(application\/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart\/form-data|text\/plain)(;.+)?$/i.test(v))
                        return original(k, v);
                    return;
                });
            },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
            }
 });
```

The problem in that case is that **the login works fine (I can't see by debugging my controller that the login is successful) however when I go back to viewing the website in HTTP, I'm not logged in. But I'm logged in when viewing in HTTPS.**

So here are my questions:

- **what does my jQuery code do that my prototype code doesn't ?**
- specially, **what makes the login works on both HTTP and HTTPS with the jQuery code** ?
- and thus, how do I **fix my prototype code to get it to behave the same way as my jQuery code ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different things I managed to get it working with the following code.

First, I used this to be able to support `withCredentials` in my XHR:

```
Ajax.Request.prototype.setRequestHeaders = Ajax.Request.prototype.setRequestHeaders.wrap(function(setHeaders) {
    setHeaders();
    if (this.options.xhrFields) {
        Object.extend(this.transport, this.options.xhrFields);
    }
});
```

Then I modified my prototype code to the following:

```
new Ajax.Request($('ajaxlogin-login-form').action, {
            xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
            method: "post",
            parameters: $('ajaxlogin-login-form').serialize(),
            onCreate: function(response) {
                var t = response.transport;
                t.setRequestHeader = t.setRequestHeader.wrap(function(original, k, v) {
                    if (/^(accept|accept-language|cookie|content-language|access-control-allow-origin|access-control-allow-headers|access-control-allow-credentials)$/i.test(k))
                        return original(k, v);
                    if (/^content-type$/i.test(k) &&
                        /^(application\/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart\/form-data|text\/plain)(;.+)?$/i.test(v))
                        return original(k, v);
                    return;
                });
            },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
            }
 });
```